# if unique_id's are equal then compare current row end value with next row start in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
data = [
['30', '12', '42'],
['30','30','100'],
['10', '70','300'],
['10','200','700'],
['20','800','900'],
['20','600','1000'],
['40','600','1200'],
['40','1100','1300'],
['90','2010','2100']
]

df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['unique_id', 'start_frame', 'end_frame'])
print(df)
```

expected output:
1)if unique_id's are equal then
2) current row end_frame should be >= next row start_frame
if next row start_frame is lesser than previous row end frame then i need to pick that unique id in a array

Comment: What is the expected output of this data?

Comment: if  next row start < previous row end then display index in a list.   output :[1,3,5,7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
['30', '12', '42'],
['30','30','100'],
['10', '70','300'],
['10','200','700'],
['20','800','900'],
['20','600','1000'],
['40','600','1200'],
['40','1100','1300'],
['90','2010','2100']
]

df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['unique_id', 'start_frame', 'end_frame'])

result = []
for i in range(1, len(df)):
  if df.loc[i, 'unique_id'] == df.loc[i-1, 'unique_id']: # if unique_id's are equal then
    if df.loc[i-1, 'end_frame'] > df.loc[i, 'start_frame']: # if next row start < previous row end
      result.append(i)

print(result)
```

Result:
`[1, 3, 5, 7]`